# possible to update cookie in javascript without page reload?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have this code I am writing:
What I am after is some info about updating the cookie (or a different approach) to accomplish the following switch without a page reload.
I have about 9 different cases for this:

```
        switch($.cookie('page')){
            case '/':
                d = level('1','#');
                $('b').on('mouseover',function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    c = '#'+makeid(6);
                    n = c.search(d);
                    $this.css({'background':c,'border-radius':'0'});
                    if(n != -1){
                        $('#complete').html('<h1>Congratulations</h1>');
                        $('#disable').show();
                        $('#complete').show();
                        $('.ok').click(function(){
                            complete('1');
                        });
                    }

                });
                break;
            case '1':
                d = level('2','');
                $('b').on('mouseover',function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    c = '#'+makeid(6);
                    n = c.search(d);
                    $this.css({'background':c,'border-radius':'0'});
                    if(n != -1){
                        $('#complete').html('<h1>Congratulations</h1>');
                        $('#disable').show();
                        $('#complete').show();
                        $('.ok').click(function(){
                            complete('2');
                        });
                    }

                });
                break;
        }

    function complete(val){
        $('#repeat').click(function(){
            $.cookie('page','/');
            location.reload();
        });
        //$('.ok').click(function(){
            $.cookie('page',val);
        //});
        clearBoard();
        $('#ok').trigger('click');
    }
```

Any ideas? 
Would it be better to just use the alternative series of if statements?

Answer (score 0):

You can set/update the value of the cookie like this:

```
$.cookie('page', 'some new value');
```

Comment: (this question is not about creating nor updating the cookie, but using the updated cookie in the same request, and it's not about PHP)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this

```
$cookie_name = 'pontikis_net_php_cookie';
$cookie_value = 'test_cookie_updated_with_php';
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
```

[click here for more](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/create-cookies-php-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Wrapped the whole thing in a function and called the function on update cookie - this works.